# Using javascript to generate divs in a table thats 6 x 6

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck on a small code and its going right over my head. So using javascript, I am creating a div and trying to display them in a 6x6 table, except without actually using the table tag. (the reason for this is I have to do something after this that the table would interfere with). Anyways, the main goal is to generate a 6x6 table of red 100px squares with javascript. Each div will have its own unique id for later purposes, however all I need help with is getting this table to display properly.. heres my code so far.

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>    

    <title></title>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function generateGrid(){
    var div = document.createElement("Div");
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height="100px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    linebreak = document.createElement("br");

    for(i=0;i<6;i++){

        for(b=0;b<6;b++){
             document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
          document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>    

    <body>
    <script>generateGrid();</script>

    </body>    

    </html>
```

For some reason its only displaying the one red box. I'm sure its a very simple error, but I was unable to find a fix, and I'm not native to javascript (java programmer) this is just for an internet programming class.

Thanks to anyone

Answer (score 0):

The code that you show creates exactly two elements, one div and one br. The [`.appendChild()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) doesn't create additional copies of the div, it just inserts or moves the first one. (Except in this case you are saying to append it to the place where it already exists, which has no effect.)

Anyway, the simple fix required is just to create a new div inside the loop:

```js
function generateGrid() {
  var div;
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 6; b++) { 
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.style.width = "10px";
      div.style.height = "10px";
      div.style.background = "red";
      div.style.display = "inline-block";
      div.style.margin = "1px";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}

generateGrid();
```

Note though that by default div elements are block elements, so you won't get six side by side on each line unless you set them to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

Rather than setting all of those styles directly, it would be nicer to set them in CSS and just assign a class:

```js
function generateGrid() {
  var div;
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 6; b++) { 
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "cell";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}

generateGrid();
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

Comment: That's getting somewhere. Except its not displaying properly. its displaying the first column of 6, but the shapes are distorted and its only the one column. Ill see if I can tamper with it from here. Thank you so much.

Comment: Okay I'm an idiot, I knew I had to do something with inline block... Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you test your layout with the browser window at different sizes, because 6 x 100px will be too wide for a narrow browser window or for many phone screens.

Comment: Oh of course, this is just perfect because the way other people were doing it took stupid amounts of code.. I found this method, but just wasn't sure how to implement it and you nailed exactly what I'm trying to do.. I upvoted but said it didn't appear because I'm new :c